# Upgrading to .net 5 assembly is missing framework version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5

I am upgrading my project to .net 5 and have the strangest error at time of build.

```
 <ResolvePackageAssets 
  ProjectAssetsFile="$(ProjectAssetsFile)"
  ProjectAssetsCacheFile="$(ProjectAssetsCacheFile)"
  ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
  ProjectLanguage="$(Language)"
  EmitAssetsLogMessages="$(EmitAssetsLogMessages)"
  TargetFramework="$(TargetFramework)"
  RuntimeIdentifier="$(RuntimeIdentifier)"
  PlatformLibraryName="$(MicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary)"
  RuntimeFrameworks="@(RuntimeFramework)"
  IsSelfContained="$(SelfContained)"
  MarkPackageReferencesAsExternallyResolved="$(MarkPackageReferencesAsExternallyResolved)"
  DisablePackageAssetsCache="$(DisablePackageAssetsCache)"
  DisableFrameworkAssemblies="$(DisableLockFileFrameworks)"
  CopyLocalRuntimeTargetAssets="$(CopyLocalRuntimeTargetAssets)"
  DisableTransitiveProjectReferences="$(DisableTransitiveProjectReferences)"
  DisableTransitiveFrameworkReferences="$(DisableTransitiveFrameworkReferences)"
  DotNetAppHostExecutableNameWithoutExtension="$(_DotNetAppHostExecutableNameWithoutExtension)"
  ShimRuntimeIdentifiers="@(_PackAsToolShimRuntimeIdentifiers)"
  EnsureRuntimePackageDependencies="$(EnsureRuntimePackageDependencies)"
  VerifyMatchingImplicitPackageVersion="$(VerifyMatchingImplicitPackageVersion)"
  ExpectedPlatformPackages="@(ExpectedPlatformPackages)"
  SatelliteResourceLanguages="$(SatelliteResourceLanguages)"
  DesignTimeBuild="$(DesignTimeBuild)"
  ContinueOnError="$(ContinueOnError)"
  PackageReferences="@(PackageReference)">
```

I am using the package from SimplyCommerce to create a modular web site and I get this error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4044 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task was not given a value for the required parameter "TargetFramework". SimplCommerce.Module.PaymentPaypalExpress   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    241
```

When I look at the assembly details I have renamed mine to warehouse crm but when I look at the target framework its showing blank. Even though I had previous set it .net 5 is their an error in the tooling im running the latest visual studio when I double click the error it takes me to this file

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

Before you ask .net 5 is install on the target machine.

[image]

[image]

This is the csproj file of the offending libary you will see their is no framework version because it is a razor sdk libary

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
 
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\PaymentPaypalExpress\Components\" />
    <Folder Include="Areas\PaymentPaypalExpress\Views\Shared\Components\" />
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Warehouse.Infrastructure\Warehouse.Infrastructure\Warehouse.Infrastructure\Warehouse.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: The `TargetFramework` is null?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the target framework in the `.csproj` file will fix the issue.

For .NET 5

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For .NET 6

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

All other versions, see also the [MSDN - frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)

Comment: This was a .net 5 issue